# How to get operations history of account?

Tags: accounts, action, eosjs, javascript

Should I analyze all the blocks or are there some methods in the `eosjs` library?

Comment: you should start your own node, and set the history plugin to filter your action

Answer (score 3):

You can simply request a node to give you the action history of an account.

Using `cleos`:

`cleos --url https://api1.eosdublin.io get actions <EOS account name>`

Using `eosjs`:

```
const eosjs = require("eosjs")
const eos = eosjs({
  httpEndpoint: 'https://api1.eosdublin.io',
  chainId: 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906'
})

async function main() {
  const actions = (await eos.getActions('<EOS account name>')).actions
  console.log(actions.map(a => a.action_trace))
}

main().catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Comment: These actions are only system action of eosio, but not all contract actions.

Comment: @Andres : I am facing the error like rror TypeError: eosjs is not a function

Comment: @Andres : I tied with terminal "cleos get actions bob" it will give response, may I know what is actual problem

Comment: @Codebrekers this answer was written using version 16.0.9 of eosjs. Nowadays, with eosjs v20.0.0, the API is different. You should check the documentation here: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/index

Answer (score 3):

1. Of course, `eosjs` provides method `getActions`. Here's an example:

   ```
   const Eos = require('eosjs');
   const api = new Eos({
       httpEndpoint: 'https://eos.greymass.com',
       chainId: 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906',
   });
   api.getActions('wangruixiwww').then(console.log);
   ```
2. You can send direct request to some API like this

   > https://eospark.com/api/account/wangruixiwww/actions?action_type=token&show_trx_small=0&show_trx_in=1&show_trx_out=1&page=1&size=50

Comment: Nice suggestion, but you would depend on a centralized source instead of being able to query it from any node on the network.

Comment: @oxfn: it will give error like TypeError: Eos is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can try another node: cleos -u https://api.eosnewyork.io get actions