# How to get transactions from an account through API call

Tags: nodeos, development, api

Is it possible to get the incoming and outgoing transactions from an account? according to this https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference link there is no way to do so. I've seen people making calls to /account/:name/history by running an own node and enabling wallet::plugin.

Comment: It may help if you can show where you've seen this. Also, are you trying to make an API call which returns all transactions that involve the account name queried, or are you asking if you can listen for incoming/outgoing actions?

Comment: In the RPC calls of Bitcoin, for instance, you can retrieve a user account with all the transactions or receive the unspent output transactions. What I found is this https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1422/how-to-get-operations-history-of-account. But it seems like account history is not supported anymore by the node and others are explaining to run your own node and include the wallet plugin. In the eosio-nodeos references I tried using the get_actions which should show the history of an account but stays empty (https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3399)

Comment: So from all the sources I've been through my current solution of getting transactions is by setting up my own node. However I prefer to retrieve it from the API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like retrieving transactions from an account works through

> [get_actions](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_actions-1)

but apparently, it doesn't show any data on the testnet, for people having this problem. Try check it on the mainnet.

Comment: I can not find get_actions in the given link, can you please check

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [demux](https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js) to watch for blocks that contain the actions you are interested in, then using websocket to push the data to your application